# Alternative to writing [i..] in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This might seem like a ridiculously simple question, but I recently started exploring Haskell.
Is there any alternative way to write [i..] , for example [0..], when making a condition? For example, when using it in a guard to see whether a given variable a < [0..]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you aim to do. What is "when making a condition"?

Comment: Also, what is `a < [0..]` supposed to mean?

Comment: Alternate question: What is wrong with `a < [0..]`? For example, the following would hold `[0,0] < [0..]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumFrom n` is equivalent to `[n..]`; in fact, I think the latter is nothing but syntactic sugar for the former.

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-400003.10 is the relevant section for defining the meaning of `[...]`. It's not *strictly* syntactic sugar, as an implementation isn't required to simply desugar the notation to a call to `enumFrom`; it just has to ensure that both have the same result.